# "New User Restrictions" documentation slightly wrong

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, new-users, privileges, help-center

Referring to [this question](/questions/274186/link-not-working-in-profile-description), I'm concerned that the [documentation of new user restrictions](/help/privileges/new-user) is not detailed enough/slightly wrong.

According to the privilege docs:

> New users cannot post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile

This is correct for posts, but **not for links in profiles**. Those still cannot be posted with <20 rep.